# PrimeNg + Angular 2/4 - Unable to load denpendencies

Tags: angular, webpack, primeng

I am trying to use PrimeNG Treeview control inside my Angualr4 app (Project was created using Visual Studio 2017 .Net core 2.0 with Angular template). I get 404 error when try to load required css dependencies. Font awesome and PrimeNG both are installed and file locations accurate, I even tried copying same files to local folder (not from node_modules) still no luck.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

Also, tried adding rules to webpack.config.js

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], include: [/node_modules/] }
```

Anyone run into same situation? PrimeNG documentation has instructions for Angular CLI, not with webpack setup like mine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

add primeng styles in your project using webpack following steps are :

**Step 1 :**

```
npm install primeng --save 
npm install --save font-awesome
```

**Step 2 :**

open **style.css** file in your project. The file contain following location `project => src => style.css`. add primeng and font-awesome styles like below :

```
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
```

Comment: I am using webpack, I don't have style.css in folder structure. Any other place to reference these files? Tried adding to boot.server.ts but no luck